# Top nav bar with position fixed behaving weirdly in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I am working on a project that uses http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/ ... We have a navigation bar with

```
position:fixed
```

and a search box floated right. In firefox 50% of this search box extends outside the div enclosing. Seems to work perfectly in chrome, sidebar automatically collapses when width is reduced etc . 
I know that elements with position fixed do not follow the regular flow.Not sure how to fix this.

here is a link to fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/avouaLzo/1/

Any help here will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
#search-page input {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    width:15%;
}
```

Working demo - [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avouaLzo/7/)

This fixing the problem in both browsers. Of course declare `width` property as you want, its only example.

Comment: This did the trick. I had to hide the search box on mobile devices when the sidebar is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
  add overflow:hidden; to #sidebar-wrapper
```

check it out @ http://jsfiddle.net/avouaLzo/2/

more advice, pls comment back

Answer (score 0):

What I tried out: Removing the width for `#wrapper`, removing the absolute positioning for `#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper` and setting a min-width for the search box.

http://jsfiddle.net/avouaLzo/5/

Now the sidebar seems to expand as before, the content uses the available space without moving out of the window and your navigation bar resizes as well. The search box itself shrinks down to a minimum value. Is it roughly what you expected?

If you going to the yellow bar as a real navigation, I would suggest a fluid solution for the navigation elements without `position`. Maybe the search box could fit in that layout as well.

Comment: I need the text to scroll under the yellow bar. Thus I had position: fixed on .top-nav. Once i put back position:fixed, search box goes out.